# Excel Power Query regex return matches and submatches using web.page

Tags: javascript, html, excel, powerquery

Using Power Query in Excel I am attempting to parse a text column to extract allocations. The original text is from an application where the user can enter the allocations in a free text field, as a result there are many different formats. I am using regex to split the allocations and handle the variety of input formats.

I am running the regex using web.page and javascript. I want to be able to return the matches and where applicable matched groups for each match as a list which can then be used in Power Query to create new rows.

The html script I have runs successfully in https://jsfiddle.net/ but does not return the expected result when run in Excel Power Query. It appears that the list items with the matches are not added, as a result the list (shown at m4) is empty.

Any help with resolving this issue, or of identifying an alternative method, would be greatly appreciated. Please note that this must work in Excel Power Query and not in Power BI.

The script is included below with an example string and regex pattern. It is modified from a script found here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94238f3e-d0a0-42fb-b58b-b309fe66e6d7/can-i-use-regular-expression-in-power-query-?forum=powerquery

```
input = "a1b2c3",

regexPattern = "\d+",

regexFlags = "gmd",

Match = (input, pattern, flags) =>
    Web.Page("
        <html>
        
        <head> </head>
        
        <body>
            <div>
                <ul id = 'Matches'></ul>
            </div>
        </body>
        
        <script>
            var input = '" & Text.Replace(Text.Replace(input, "\", "\\"), "'", "\'") & "';
            var pattern = '" & Text.Replace(Text.Replace(pattern, "\", "\\"), "'", "\'") & "';
            var flags = '" & Text.Replace(Text.Replace(flags, "\", "\\"), "'", "\'") & "';
            var re = new RegExp(pattern, flags);

            try {
                var m = getMatches(input, re);      
                var list = document.getElementById('Matches');
                var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                for ( var i = 0; i < m.length; i++ ){
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.textContent = JSON.stringify(m);
                    fragment.appendChild(li);                                      
                }
                list.appendChild(fragment);
            } catch (e) {
            document.write(e.message);
            }

            function getMatches(str, re) {
                var matches = [];
                var match;
                while (match = re.exec(str)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= match.indices.length; i++) {
                        if (match[i] != null) {
                            matches.push(match[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return matches;
            }
        </script>

        </html>
    "),

m0 = Match(input, regexPattern, regexFlags),
m1 = m1[Data]{0}[Children],
m2 = m1{0}[Children],
m3 = m2{1},
m4 = m3{0}[Children],
```

Comment: For the javascript to work in Power Query, you need to determine the browser in the Power query first [How to](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/How-to-use-JavaScript-inside-power-query-for-data-extraction/ba-p/1632844). Once you determine the browser, you need to check the js syntax compatibility for that browser engine. Unless compatible syntax used, it will return nothing. I believe it currently uses IE11.

Comment: It is running IE11.